# On Windows, difference between bin directory and cmd directory (in the context of "C:\Program Files\git\cmd|bin\git.exe

Tags: windows

I'm reading the book ["Happy git and Github for the UseR"](https://happygitwithr.com/rstudio-see-git.html) (specifically related to R studio, relevant for context but not for the actual question)

The author explains how to set up R Studio to find the `git.exe` by setting the path to the git executable to `C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe`. She then makes an emphasis that one should not used `C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe`, but does not explain the difference between `cmd` and `bin` in this context.

Why would I have two different `git.exe` in two different locations, and what is the difference between the two? And why would the author stress not to use the one under the `cmd` directory?

Comment: In recent Git 4 Windows (I checked back to 2.26) these are actually identical - they both operate as shortcuts that first set up the necessary environment (e.g. prepending directories to $PATH) before calling the "real" git.exe under `Git/mingw64/bin/` Generally you *should* call either wrapper (from anywhere except a mingw console) so that git picks up matching dependencies. Once upon a time `Git/cmd` held instead a file `git.cmd` - a batch file which did **not** work with other tools well. I think they dropped this in favour of the wrapper `.exe` but kept the duplicate dir to avoid breakage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question can be inferred from this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14452151

Essentially, everything in the cmd folder is meant to be used for Windows CMD, and is actually just a wrapper for the 'real' executable. Think of them as .cmd or .bat files but with an .exe extension (even though they aren't literally). R Studio is likely incompatible with using the wrapper and thus needs the one in the bin directory.